# Adding product to WooCommerce cart

Tags: functions, woocommerce-offtopic

I have a product category called mobile. In every mobile category product purchase I need to add a free product and it's `ID` is 1245 to the cart automatically & customer needs to see a message that it is a free product with mobile. They can also delete the product 1245.

How can I do this? Is there any plugin to help?

I tried this code but didn't work & I don't know how to get category either.

```
add_action( 'init', 'add_product_to_cart' );

function add_product_to_cart() {

      $product_id =1245;
      $found = false;

      //check if product already in cart
      if ( sizeof( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() ) > 0 ) {

            foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key =>      $values ) {
            $_product = $values['data'];

            if ( $_product->id == $product_id )
                $found = true;
            }

         // if product not found, add it
         if ( ! $found )
            $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id );
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had used [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-multiple-free-gift/) for similar scenario. Please check it's BOGO (Buy One Get One) feature. That will address your requirement.